# Why the function of address.transfer() only can send 1ether in my contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Why the function of `address.transfer()` only can send 1ether in my contract? It will report errors when the value greater than 1 ether or less than 1 ether.

My code:

```js
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Lottery{

  uint public winn;

  //抽奖者
  struct lottery{

    uint money;   //奖金
    address name;    //名字(地址)
    
  }


  //庄家地址
  address private bankerAddress = 0x8b3234612c7D3b805F4c9CF1Aa55Cc47B82A0769;

  //得奖者数量
  uint32 public count;

  //得奖者集合
  lottery public l;



  //初始化
  constructor()public {
    count=0;
  }


  event getRandom (
    uint indexed _win);



  //开始抽奖的函数,返回奖金
  function start() public payable{
    
    
    //随机数生成
    uint win= uint(keccak256(now, msg.sender, now)) % 100;
    
    win = win % 12 +1;
    winn = win;
    
    
    l.money = winn;
    l.name = msg.sender;
    
    //发奖金操作
    msg.sender.transfer(winn*10000000000000000);


    //监听事件
    getRandom(winn);
  }

  function () public payable{}
}
```

Below is javascript code:

```js
lotteryInstance.start.sendTransaction({
  from: '0x8b3234612c7D3b805F4c9CF1Aa55Cc47B82A0769',
  value: 10000000000000000,
  gas: 210000,
  gasPrice: web3.toWei('1000', 'gwei')
});
```

And the error messages:

> MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":7309825988666,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0xf8721f85e8d4a510008303345094bcd5d351e5850774d1f720328dac1c8732d68eb7872386f26fc1000084be9a6555822d45a0a07b903c493ba6dee96a54bc74344d1c668cd3d9e8a7c757fdc5daa664ff4271a01bb6799a02054ecf1c8c5be51d6748b2c086eb330091b2e0500d43e756666f69"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":7309825988666,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0xf8721f85e8d4a510008303345094bcd5d351e5850774d1f720328dac1c8732d68eb7872386f26fc1000084be9a6555822d45a0a07b903c493ba6dee96a54bc74344d1c668cd3d9e8a7c757fdc5daa664ff4271a01bb6799a02054ecf1c8c5be51d6748b2c086eb330091b2e0500d43e756666f69"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Answer (score 0):

In your JS code below:

```
lotteryInstance.start.sendTransaction({
    from: '0x8b3234612c7D3b805F4c9CF1Aa55Cc47B82A0769',
    value: 10000000000000000, // Here is the amount of ETH you give to start fuction
    gas: 210000,
    gasPrice: web3.toWei('1000', 'gwei')
});
```

The tx is failing maybe because you're giving (ETH) an amount that you may not have! Do you have `value: 10000000000000000` many Ethers?

If no, then pass some amount you have, as you haven't given any conditions about the amount in your contract, you can give the smallest possible amount.

PS: The ETH your contract is receiving is not stored anywhere, it may lead to **loss of Ethers.**

Comment: The value`s company is wei.

Comment: Today,I was replace transfer with send, It could transfer to the contract address when I call the function of start in web3,but the current account just can get 1 ether

Comment: Try passing the value this way : `web3.toWei('1000', 'gwei')`, maybe this would help.

Comment: Your suggestion is very good！and I have solved this problem of only can transfer 1 ether. This question is I clean metamask`cache after I use the banker`adress to transfer 10 ether to contract,The palyer can get enough ether if I don`t clean the cache.But I don`t know why ? Does it clean the ether at contract`address?

Comment: I guess it does if you're using custom RPC or Localhost Network. But that's another question you'll have to search or ask.